# Getting tz is not a function error when testing a method in Angular 2 service that uses moment-timezone

Tags: angular, unit-testing, webpack, momentjs, karma-runner

I am getting `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_moment__.tz is not a function` when testing a method that uses `moment.tz(time)` functionality. 
When I test just a dummy function that uses `moment.js` everything is alright.

I checked karma and webpack configs but they don't mention moment anywhere. By my reasoning if moment works in unit-tests like that without being explicitly mentioned in webpack and karma configs, so should moment-timezone.

Here is the unit test file for the service:

```
//note.service.spec.ts
import {TestBed, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";
import {NoteService} from './note.service';

import * as moment from 'moment'; //xavtodo: maybe not needed

describe('NoteService', () => {
  let service: NoteService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting())
        .configureTestingModule({
          providers: [NoteService]
        });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
  });

  beforeEach(inject([NoteService], (s: NoteService) => {
    service = s;
  }));

  it('should be created', inject([NoteService], (service: NoteService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('DUMMY WITH MOMENTJS', inject([NoteService], (service: NoteService) => { //so this one is working with moment.js
      expect(service.dummy()).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('DUMMY WITH MOMENT-TIMEZONE', inject([NoteService], (service: NoteService) => { //this one isn't with moment timezone
    expect(service.dummytz()).toBeTruthy();
  }));

});
```

The `dummy` and `dummytz` functions in note.service.ts that I am testing to isolate the error:

```
dummy(): Moment{
  return moment();
}

dummytz(): Moment{
  return moment.tz('Europe/London');
}
```

Obviously, it looks like the tz() function is not defined on moment, webpack doesn't pick up on the moment-timezone in unit tests, but it picks it alright in the application.

This is `webpack.unit.test.js` config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

console.log('///////////////////////////UNIT TEST');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: commonConfig.module,

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'main.css', disable: false, allChunks: true})
    ]
}
```

Comment: are you importing moment-timezone into your service or wherever you are using it

Comment: Don't have to. Just added it to `package.json` and when I use `moment.tz()` the webpack takes care of that.

Answer (score 4):

How & where are you importing moment? It looks like you are missing

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
```

More details [are here](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) on how to use `moment().tz`

Comment: I dropped this line `require('moment-timezone');` at the top of `note.service.spec.ts` and the tests are turning green. However, every time I test a component or service method that uses timezone functionality, I will have to drop `require('moment-timezone');` in spec file. Is there a better way? I don't have to require moment-timezone for the production code to work, so why is it necessary for the unit tests?

Comment: I recommend making a `spec-helper.js` that does the require for moment-timezone, then you can either have all tests require that file, or include that file in your karma.options.js `files: []` array

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks for help @olore